# Delete h4 tag on footer Prestashop

Tags: html, css, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm novice, i want to remove an h4 tag and replace it with a div tag on PrestaShop Footer. Version Prestashop : 1.6.20

This is HTML Code

```
 <h4>{l s='Information' mod='blockcms'}</h4>
```

I do this :

```
<div class="footer_h4">{l s='Information' mod='blockcms'}</div>
```

This is CSS Code / How insert class "footer_h4"?

```
.footer-container #footer h4 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #222;
  margin: 0 0 23px 0;
  cursor: pointer; }
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .footer-container #footer h4 {
      position: relative;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      padding-bottom: 13px; }
      .footer-container #footer h4:after {
        display: block;
        content: "\f055";
        font-family: "FontAwesome";
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 1px; }
      .footer-container #footer h4.active:after {
        content: "\f056"; } }
  .footer-container #footer h4 a {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #222;
  }

@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .footer-container #footer h4 a:before,
  .footer-container #footer #block_contact_infos h4 {display: none;}
}
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you studied basic CSS selector syntax? This is almost painfully fundamental.

```
.footer-container .footer_h4 {
```

If you want to keep the current styles for the h4 tag, add a second selector using list format:

```
.footer-container #footer h4, 
.footer-container .footer_h4 {
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok and this? It's the same principle?

```
.footer-container #footer h4:after,
.footer-container #footer_h4 {
```